# Spring Boot and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am having a hard time understanding how Spring Boot (v1.3.3) handles the X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest header. My understanding is that this header tells Spring Boot to return, for requests without an authenticated session, a 401-Unauthorized error rather than a 302-Found with a location to the login page.

I have set up my AngularJS client to send this header for any routing, and then configured an $http interceptor to act on the 401 error by displaying a dialog. Doesn't work for me, with a Spring Boot server with no additional security configuration.

With some investigation with CURL:

1. It seems that the `-H "Accept: application/json"` header also needs to be provided.

`curl -v -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" localhost:9080/` returns a 302, while `curl -v -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:9080/` returns a 401.

Questions: Why is the application/json header required as well? Can I configure it differently (i.e. not require application/json header)? Should I configure it this way, or take another approach? The reason I don't want to require the application/json header is because I am not allowing public access to some resources, such as HTML templates and JS code, and want a 401 returned for these resources as well.

2. It seems that the JSESSIONID cookie may be affecting the response.

`curl -v -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:9080/` returns a 401, while `curl -v -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=63EA6E09F64B98938E4495DF9898323A" localhost:9080/'` returns a 302.

Questions: Why does the presence of the (valid) JSESSIONID cookie make any difference?

I have looked at the source code for Spring Security and Spring Boot and I just cannot put together the pieces. Any help is much appreciated.